# CIFS mount not on showing correct owner

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I have a CIFS mount on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. getcifsacl shows the correct domain user as owner but not getfacl shows unix root user as owner.
Not sure what i am missing.

wbinfo -t

wbinfo -n

wbinfo -S  give same id as frim "id "

smbclient -L $HOSTNAME -U $domain_admin%$domain_passwd -d 3, works fine

This is an issue since application running wil check user permisison based on getfacl.

Adding comment:

I was able to fix the mount and permission on Virtual Machine but same is not working on pod..

mount.cifs   -o nofail,cifsacl,user=,pass=,dom=,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30

This works on Virtual Machine but not on Pod. provided capabilities - SYS_ADMIN - DAC_READ_SEARCH - CAP_SETGID - CAP_SETUID
Tested on Ubuntu and RHEL

Comment: What are the mount options of your cifs-mount ? To make "Windows-SMB" permission "Posix" compatible there is a lot of configuration needed.

Comment: Hi All, I was able to fix the mount and permission on Virtual Machine but same is not working on pod..

Comment: If you do not provide us details (edit your question), we can not help you.

Comment: mount.cifs <mount source using SMB protocol> <target on pod> -o nofail,cifsacl,user=<username>,pass=<password>,dom=<domain>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30

This works on Virtual Machine but not on Pod. provided capabilities - SYS_ADMIN
            - DAC_READ_SEARCH
            - CAP_SETGID
            - CAP_SETUID